# CSS: how to horizontally center video on mobile screen with 100% height and overflow width?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html5-video, centering

In the following code, I am trying to center a video to full mobile screen height, and wanted to evenly overflow the video width to left and right side.

**style #0** shows the original size

**style #1** shows me trying to center the video, but the video shifts to the right

**style #2** shows the fix, the video is perfectly centered, however, the transformation will cause issues when our web site's language is in RTL (right aligned language, such as Arabic).

I wanted to find a way to properly center the video without using any transformation (i.e. do not use **style #2**), any good suggestions?

**cshtml:**

```
<div class="videodiv">
    <video class="webvideo"></video>
</div>
```

**Style #0:**

This shows the original video in its natural ratio

```
.videodiv {
    text-align: center;
}

.videodiv .webvideo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

**Style #1:**
under this css, when height is 100%, the video width actually overflows the screen, the left side is aligned with left screen border, the right side overflows.

```
.videodiv {
    text-align: center;
}

.videodiv .webvideo {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

**Style #2:**

```
.videodiv {
    text-align: center;
}

.videodiv .webvideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try `height:100%` and `width:auto` for `<video>` ?

Comment: how about  `width:auto;` and `height:100vh;` for `videodiv` or `video`?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph  yeah, please look at style #1, that's it

Comment: @GianLorenzoAbaño yeah, we tried it in style #1, it shifted to the right

Comment: Can you provide the link to your video? So its much easier to do things on the snippet or jsfiddle..

Comment: @Gosi it's actually not a video video, it's a video from camera capture, my project is hosted on a localhost right now... sorry

Answer (score 1):

Will this work? Tested on **Chrome,** **Firefox** and **Samsung Internet**.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="video_container">
<video class="video" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay muted>
</video>
</div>

<style>
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.video_container, .video {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
</style>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="videodiv">
    <video height="100%" controls>
      <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

- The simplest way to do is to use grid system. For reference go through below links
- Also give `height: 100%` on the video, it'll take the 100% height along with required width

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Thank you Nazifa, did you check out the browser support? Seems display: grid is only supported in latest versions of browsers.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid&search=Grid please check this link and bootstrap also use grid :)